# How to avoid landing page redirect in Django

Tags: python, django, performance, redirect

I have a use case wherein when I hit the django app using `http://localhost:5000` , it has to redirect to `http://localhost:5000/target` . I am doing this in `views.py` as

```
def landing_page(request):
    """Index page for the application."""
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('target'))
```

I want to avoid this redirect as it has performance issues as per [this](https://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/high-performance-sites-rule-11-avoid-redirects-7209.html) , but retain this behavior.

Is there any way to do this.

Comment: Why are you doing the redirect in the first place? Why but serve the target page on `/`?

Comment: You can serve the landing page at both URLs, but it's preferable to have a page available at only one URL.

Comment: If you're okay with serving the content at both URLs, but only want to have one urlconf, a hack can be to have your web server rewrite your request (e.g., using mod_rewrite in Apache). I don't advise doing it, but you should be aware it's possible. That said, I'm not aware of a way to kick a user from / to /target without using a redirect.